# Entity Framework: how to do a nested 'select distinct .. where in' using polygon types

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, polygon

We have the following case/query in EF:

```
    return await dbcontext.TopografischePercelen
            .AsQueryable()
            .Where(p => p.PeriodeId == 43)
            .Select(t => new
            {
                t.Id,

                // Polygon array  
                Omtrek =
                    t.Gewaspercelen.SelectMany(gp => gp.OverlappendeReferentiepercelen)
                    .Select(r => r.Referentieperceel.GeoData.RDNewGeo)
                    .Distinct()  // <-- cannot use this with polygon type
                    .ToArray(),

                // other data
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

But this doesn’t work. I gives the runtime error:

> The geometry data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

It should return an array of `TopografischPerceel` entities which each having a property `Omtrek` containing an 'array of Polygon' which is based on the polygons referenced by several `Gewasperceel` records which are child records of `TopografischPerceel`:

Relations:

```
TopografischePerceel
\-* Gewasperceel
    \-* Referentieperceel (has one polygon)
```

Any way to get this working?

Sample data:

```
 Topo1
|- gewasperc1
|  \- refperc1
\- gewasperc2
   \- refperc1
Topo2
|- gewasperc3
|  \- refperc2
\- gewasperc4
   \- refperc3
```

Should result in

```
Topo1
|- Id = 1
\- omtrek = [refperc1-geo]
Topo2
|- Id = 2
\- omtrek = [refperc2-geo, refperc3-geo]
```

But when I don’t use ‘distinct’ the query will run, but returns:

```
Topo1
|- Id = 1
\- omtrek = [refperc1-geo, refperc1-geo]
Topo2
|- Id = 2
\- omtrek = [refperc2-geo, refperc3-geo]
```

Comment: Getting the "MAX" of a polygon doesn't make sense. What would you define as a "maximum" polygon? They are shapes, not numbers.

Comment: @Larnu Hmmm, I understand ‘max’ makes no sense, so I removed that part in the question. But distinct would make sense in the way I want remove duplicate polygones (which there sometimes are)

Comment: Find a unique data structure like an ID and group on it and take the first `RDNewGeo` instance from the group.

Comment: @Igor ‘and take the first RDNewGeo instance’ well thats the problem, how can I do this inside the query in the question... It’s not like i only need just one array. There are multiple ‘TopografischPerceel’ record and each have there own array of polygons, which need to be distinct.